# Issues aligning links that appear on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to design a tumblr theme. I've set up a div with four buttons at the bottom of each post. One of these buttons is a share button. You hover over the share button and a div appears with links (you click and a new window opens and the post gets shared where ever you selected it to be shared).

In the example below: when I roll over the icon with the mouse, it comes up aligned to the left.

IMAGE HERE: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1O3Ee_1Z5cRTDdaSTBQNW5mM0U/view?usp=sharing

Also, when I resize the page, the menu ends up being in a totally different position.

I would like for the menu to appear as it appears in this image. I want the menu to appear directly beneath the div of buttons. I would like this menu to remain in the same position when in the page is resized or is a mobile viewport size. (This is a mock up I made with a photo editor) I've tried various adjustments in my code, etc with no avail.

IMAGE HERE: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1O3Ee_1Z5cRX3hPd2ZGekJhU0U/view?usp=sharing

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
.showme{ 
    display: none;
    width:100px;
    height:120px;
    text-align:right;
    margin-top:30px;
    z-index:5;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;  
}
.showhim:hover .showme{
    display : block;
    z-index:5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="showhim"> 
    <li style="float:right; margin-left:5px; list-style-type:none; line-height:0px; padding-top:1px;">
        <i class="fa fa-share-square fa-lg"></i>
    </li>
    <div class="showme">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={Permalink}" target="_blank">Twitter</a><br/>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={Permalink}" target="_blank">Facebook</a><br/>
        <a href="http://plus.google.com/share?url={Permalink}" target="_blank">Google Plus</a><br/>
        <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/" target="_blank">Pinterest</a><br/>
        <a href="mailto:?subject=&body={Permalink}" target="_blank">Email</a>
    </div>
```

I am open to any method to try and get this to work. I also have no problems with making this an onClick event rather than a hover event. My guess is that an onClick event would be smarter for mobile users (I'd love some input on this).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using position: absolute; and float: right; ? When you position absolute you remove the element from the document flow and float is irrelevant. [Read up on positioning.](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) You also haven't posted any of your javascript. If you can clean up your unused styles and post your JS it will make it easier to help you.

Comment: @A.Wolff give the guy a break! he/she is new to the concept!

Comment: I built my hover thing off of this example: http://jsfiddle.net/cor6bay6/1/ -- There is no JS in the JS window.

Answer (score 0):

At the minimum, you'll want to add something like:

```
right: 0;
```

to the CSS of `.showme`. This will place the block with its right border aligned with the right border of the containing block.

Note that the containing block is not necessarily the immediate parent. You probably want to add:

```
position: relative;
```

to the CSS of whichever element you want to use as the containing block (probably `.showhim`).